# Apache2 can not parse html under mac os x 10.8.5

Tags: django, macos, apache2

Environment: Mac OS X 10.8.5, and Apache2.

Recently, I am build apache2+django+mysql.
**But I found my apache2 can not parse html, it just show the html code in browser.**

How should I do for this problem?
Thank you very much.

Comment: You need to be more specific in describing your problem, and show the code and setup you're using. As Max says, Apache has nothing to do with parsing HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apache **does not parse HTML**. What you are experiencing is most likely an encoding problem or invalid HTML (browsers tolerate a lot, so it has to be very wrong...). Use the standard `httpd.conf` and point a web browser to your domain and see what happens. Most likely the problem is somewhere else in your stack.

Comment: Thank you so much. I got the problem I had. And you let me know about what's the job of the web server more clear. Thank you.